# Django - Get highest value from each user

Tags: python, django, database

I have this models:

Models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Name')


class Grad(models.Model):
    grad = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Grad') 
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Order')


class Number(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='User', on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    grad = models.ForeignKey(Grad, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Grad', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

View:

```
user_numbers = Number.objects.all()
```

Get example:

[image]

But i want only get the highest order grad value to each user:

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I think you need to use this **from django.db.models import Avg, Max, Min, Sum** ```.aggregate(Max('Grad_Òrder'))```   this is just an idea of what you can use ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate values you need:

```py
from django.db.models import Max

# ...

        # In your view:
        data = Number.objects.values('user__name').annotate(
            order=Max('grad__order'),
            grad='grad__grad',
        )
        user_numbers = data.all()
```

Comment: Thanks! This help me.